# Can a Binding value be created as a XAML Page resource?

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, design-time

Hi for rapid UI testing of Binding data at design-time in a UWP app, I was wondering if there was a way to create Binding values as resources in XAML.   So instead of having to create a model, instantiate that model at design-time in Page.Resources, I just wanted to create essentially some constants I could use as Bindings.

Here are some examples of where I’d like the test bindings to work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding title, ConverterParameter=lower, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
```

Given that scenario is there a way I could say define title as a named key with a string value that would work above?

Note that I am using Binding and not x:Bind since I want to use design-time data and I don’t want to have to rely on using the FallbackValue parameter.

Thanks for any ideas!

Rick

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to a static resource directly, but you can bind to a property of a static resource instead.

You can create a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` which would have properties like `Title`. You would then create an instance of this class and store it as resource:

```
Application.Current.Resources[ "Data" ] = new MyDataClass();
```

Now you could use it in binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, Source={StaticResource Data}}" />
```

Comment: OK so a class is still required as a minimum.  That's a neat idea, I'll check it out, could be a way to streamline some quick UX testing.   Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need at least the class. The reason is probably that the source of binding should usually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you knew the value will be "hardcoded" into the resource, you could possibly do something like Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Title}}", but that would be useless, as you could do directly Text="{StaticResource Text}" anyway. If you expect the value to change, the class is the best option.

Comment: That's very helpful.   Out of curiosity, is it possible to use a Binding' FallbackValue that get's it's value from a StaticResource?   I tried using this:  <x:String x:Key="greeting">my category</x:String> along with Text="{Binding Status, FallbackValue={StaticResource greeting}'}" with a TextBlock but that is ignored in UWP XAML.